# Android view/fragment issue

Tags: java, android, fragment

So I'm trying to load different contents in a `ListView` when I press on specific buttons but it only loads the first that I tried to load (and only after I have pressed it twice). I can't find what I've done wrong.

Here's the code that creates the view in witch I show the content:

```
public class ContentQuery extends Fragment {
    private List<String> contents_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static final String TAG = contentQuery.class.getSimpleName();
    private String uri = "";

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View lv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contents_list, container, false);
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        getContent(); // Sets contents_list
        ((ListView) lv).setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, contents_list));
        return lv;
    }
}
```

I think it might be because I should in some way destroy it but I'm pretty new to android dev.

```
tag = ContentQuery.TAG;
ContentQuery contentqueryfragment = null;
final Fragment foundFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(tag);
if (foundFragment != null && uri != old_uri) {
    fragment = foundFragment;
    contentqueryfragment = (ContentQuery) fragment;
    old_uri = uri;          
} else {
    contentqueryfragment = new ContentQuery();
    contentqueryfragment.setUri(uri.toString());
    fragment = contentqueryfragment;
}
```

And after:

```
if (fragment.isAdded())
{
    tr.show(fragment);
} else
{
    tr.remove(fragment);
    tr.add(R.id.content, fragment, tag);
    tr.show(fragment);

}
tr.commit();

currentUri = uri;
currentContentFragmentTag = tag;
```

Comment: You should not be calling `super.onActivityCreated` in `onCreateView`. You should only be creating and setting up your views in `onCreateView`.  Also, if your view is only a `ListView` then you should be using a `ListFragment` instead of a regular `Fragment`.

Comment: Ok so I removed `super.onActivityCreated` but I don't think I can use `ListFragment` because I have a `Fragment` I use for settings and I load one or the other by setting it to a `Fragment`.

Comment: `ListFragment` is just a subclass of `Fragment`. You can assign a `ListFragment` to a `Fragment`.

Comment: Then I'm doing something else wrong, I edited my first post with the code that calls the fragment

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update the content within the List a good approach would be to separate the List, ListAdapter and ListView. When data needs to be updated, update the contents of the list and notify the Adapter that the list contents changed.

eg.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, contents_list);
((ListView) lv).setAdapter(adapter);

...

button.onClickListener(...) {
   contents_list.clear();

   ... populate list with new data ...

   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Now I've done that but it's still not working might be on the calling code (I edited my first post). It seems that it gets stuck in just showing and not creating a new `fragment`

Comment: Can you paste your error/debug logs? If you are simply changing the content of a list, you should not need to work with or need to swap Fragments in and out. Maybe your code needs to be re-factored. Also, did you change the ContentQuery to extend ListFragment instead of Fragment? (as it was made to handle list views such as yours)

Comment: There is no error or even warnings except when I change the `Fragment` to `ListFragment` "Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'" I tried to create a `ListView` named list but it didn't fixed the error. Currently I'm trying to fix it by changing the 2 peaces above with if's. It goes first in the 2 `else` and then it gets stuck in the `if's`

Comment: The error you're seeing is because when using a `ListFragment`, in the xml layout for the ListFragment the ID must be list. eg `android:id="@id/android:list` in the xml layout for the fragment. Lemme know if this helps

Comment: Maybe it wasn't really clear in my comment, but I did looked up to find that I had to create a `ListView` with `android:id="@id/android:list` but it didn't fixed the error. Is it really necessary ? My main issue is the way I create the fragment that won't work properly (thanks for your help)